# Caesar problem code generating "error: implicitly declaring library function 'strlen' with type 'unsigned long (const char *)'

Tags: cs50

I am doing the CS50 course and am on week 2. One of the problems of week 2 is called "Caesar". Essentially you have to write code which cyphers text by shifting letters that use the users inputted preferred number. After running my code I keep getting this error

> ```
> "error: implicitly declaring library function 'strlen' with
>      type 'unsigned long (const char *)'
>      [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
>    for(i = 0, l = strlen(text); i < n; i++)"
> ```

This is the code:

```c
int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    string n = argv[1];
    int y = argc;
    
    int key = get_int("./caesar ");//getting the number from the user
    int k = (key);//assigning key a variable name.
    string text = get_string("plaintext: ");//letting the user input their text.
    if (key < 1)//Trying to make limit for acceptable input.
    {
        printf("ERROR");
        return 1;
    }
    
    int l;
    int i;
    
    //for loop containing the encipher process
    for(i = 0, l = strlen(text); i < n; i++)
    {
        if(isalpha(i))
        {
             if (isupper[i])
            {
                printf("ciphertext: %c",(text[i] + k)%26 + 65);
            }
            else (islower[i])
            {
                printf("ciphertext: %c",(text[i] + k)%26 + 65);
            }
        }
    }
    printf("ciphertext: %c", d || c);
    return;
    
    int checking_key(int y,string n)
    int num = argc;
    string key = y;
    int num_key = atoi(key);
    
    if(argc != 2)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        if (num_key > 0)
        {
            return num_key;
        }
        else
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [man strlen](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strlen):

> **Synopsis**
>
> #include <string.h>
> size_t strlen(const char *s);

Just like one needs to "include" `cs50.h` to use any of the `get_*` functions, `string.h` must be "include"d to access its functions, eg `strlen`.

Additionally (per comments):

The "ordered comparison" in the compile error

```
ordered comparison between pointer and integer ('int' and 'string' (aka 'char *')) [-Werror] for(i = 0, l = strlen(text); i < n; i++)
```

is `i < n`. Error says one of them is an int and one of them is a string.

On closer inspection this program is a *long* way from a clean compile.  Recommend you follow along with the spec and "*approach this problem one step at a time*"

Comment: ordered comparison between pointer and integer
      ('int' and 'string' (aka 'char *')) [-Werror]
    for(i = 0, l = strlen(text); i < n; i++)                                                                                                                                                                                                                       This was the result after your suggestion. I feel we are moving in the right direction but how do wenow resolve this?

Comment: More info added to answer.